# Move input element to the center of the div

Tags: html, css

I need to move form input element from left to the center of div element.
I tried to solve this problem by margin: auto and position: relative.
The second way works, but there is a small problem. When I change the size 
of the browser window, the input element changes its position. How to avoid it 
by solving the first problem at the same time?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77h4A.jpg)

```css
#stretch5 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  height: 30em;
  background-image: url(img/newsletter.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.frame {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25em;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: scale(0.8975, 0.8975) translate(-68.5808px, -31.2925px);;
}
.frame h2 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.frame input[type=submit] {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #f7e0cd;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0 none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 2em;  
}
```

```html
<div id="stretch5" class="newsletter-opt-in"> 
    <div class="frame">
      <h2>Join our<span class="vip">VIP list</span></h2>
      <p class="vip-list-paragraph">For the exclusive tips, free resources and best tips</p>
      <form action="#">
        <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE">
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in `.frame input` to change the element `display` to `flex;`. So the button is displayed in the middle of the page even if the page is reduced

```
.frame input[type=submit] {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #f7e0cd;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 0 none;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 2em;  
}
```

I hope it will solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just apply `text-align:center` to the `form`.

```css
#stretch5 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30em;
  background-image: url(img/newsletter.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.frame {
  height: 25em;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.frame h2 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}

.frame input[type=submit] {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: #f7e0cd;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="stretch5" class="newsletter-opt-in">
  <div class="frame">
    <h2>Join our<span class="vip">VIP list</span></h2>
    <p class="vip-list-paragraph">For the exclusive tips, free resources and best tips</p>
    <form action="#">
      <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```